# How to derive a truth value from the following formula, one where the formula is T and one where it is F

Tags: logic, proof-writing, predicate-logic

Hi Guys I am trying to derive a structure from the formula where truth value for one structure is F and for another is T. I haven't seen a formula like this before so I am slightly confused.

this is the formula

```
∀ X • p(X , a) ∧ p(a, X ) ∧ (∃ Y • p(X , Y ) ∧ p(Y , X ))
```

the small a inside the brackets is really throwing me off. What would be the best way to proceed with this?

Comment: Could you try to be more specific? What do you mean by structure? Because it doesn't seem to be the classical notion of [structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure).

Comment: @GiorgioMossa hi basically so if it was something simpler such as the following  ∀ X • ∀ Y • p(X , Y ) ⇒ q(X , Y ), then a structure that would be true is p is loves and q is marriedTo so to make it true it would translated as if X loves Y then X is married to Y

Comment: I think that what you have to do is to find **two** structures $M, N$ such that $M \vDash \varphi$ and $N \nvDash \varphi$, where $\varphi := ∀x \ [p(x , a) ∧ p(a, x ) ∧ ∃y \ (p(x,y) ∧ p(y,x))]$. I think that $a$ is an individual *constant*.

Comment: @user5647516 I still don't follow, a structure is not something that can be true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

A simple way to "falsify" the formula:

> $∀x \ [p(x,a) ∧ p(a,x) ∧ ∃y \ (p(x,y) ∧ p(y,x))]$

is to consider the domain $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers and interpret the individual *constant* $a$ as denoting the number $0$.

Finally, we have to interpret the binary predicate $p$ with the "less-then" ($<$) relation.

Clearly, $x < 0$ is *false* for any $x \in \mathbb N$ and thus:

> $\mathbb N \nvDash ∀x \ [p(x,a) ∧ p(a,x) ∧ ∃y \ (p(x,y) ∧ p(y,x))]$.

Comment: thank you that makes a lot of sense now